# Custom plugin blocking upgrade

Tags: plugins, upgrades

I've created a plugin which I'm adding to my project like this in `composer.json`:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packagist.phpcomposer.com"
    },
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "plugins/plugin-name"
    }
],
```

And now I'm trying to run some upgrades via terminal and getting:

> Root composer.json requires `package-name/plugin-name dev-upgrade/craft4`, found `package-name/plugin-name[dev-develop]` but it does not match your constraint and is therefore not installable. Make sure you fix the constraint as packages installed from symlinked path repos are updated even in partial updates and the one from the lock file can thus not be used.

which I don't understand. Where do `dev-upgrade/craft4` and `[dev-develop]` come from?